# Math.random() returns the same number across instances [Java]

Tags: java, random

I'm trying to create a particle that wanders around by randomly rotating its velocity vector. I'm using LibGdx and Java 11.

This is my Cell class (I didn't want to name it particle):

```
package me.kolterdyx.testgame.custom;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;


public class Cell {

    private Vector2 vel;
    private float deviationFactor = 15f;

    public Cell(){
        this.vel = Vector2.X;
    }


    public void update(){
        float deviation = (float)(Math.random()*deviationFactor-deviationFactor/2f);
        vel.rotateDeg(deviation);
    }


}
```

This is my Main class:

```
package me.kolterdyx.testgame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import me.kolterdyx.testgame.custom.Cell;

public class Main extends ApplicationAdapter {
    Cell[] cells;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        cells = new Cell[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            // Here I create a new instance for each index of the array
            cells[i] = new Cell();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        for(int i=0;i<cells.length;i++){
            //Here I update and display each cell
            Cell c = cells[i];
            c.update();
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see, I create two independent instances of the Cell class. However, when I run the project, all I can see is both cells following exactly the same path. They look like they are only one cell because they overlap perfectly. I've tried creating independent Random instances using the ID of each Cell as the seed, but that has only achieved a difference of about 1.2 between the random numbers, but they are still very close and the cells never separate. What could be causing this problem?

EDIT: More info

I have printed the deviation from two cells and their resulting velocity angle. I have set Cell 0 to always have a deviation of 0:

```
Cell 0: Deviation=-0.0 | New velocity angle=0.0
Cell 1: Deviation=-3.7252638 | New velocity angle=356.27475
---
Cell 0: Deviation=-0.0 | New velocity angle=356.27475
Cell 1: Deviation=-1.5686669 | New velocity angle=354.70605
---
Cell 0: Deviation=0.0 | New velocity angle=354.70605
Cell 1: Deviation=3.9682944 | New velocity angle=358.67438
---
Cell 0: Deviation=-0.0 | New velocity angle=358.67438
Cell 1: Deviation=3.6621578 | New velocity angle=2.3365214
---
Cell 0: Deviation=-0.0 | New velocity angle=2.3365214
Cell 1: Deviation=-10.350971 | New velocity angle=351.98553
---
Cell 0: Deviation=0.0 | New velocity angle=351.98557
Cell 1: Deviation=-8.096683 | New velocity angle=343.88885
---
Cell 0: Deviation=-0.0 | New velocity angle=343.88885
Cell 1: Deviation=11.823002 | New velocity angle=355.71188
---
Cell 0: Deviation=-0.0 | New velocity angle=355.71188
Cell 1: Deviation=5.809546 | New velocity angle=1.5214165
```

For some reason, the deviation value of Cell 1 is added to the velocity angle of both Cells, even though the deviation value is created locally inside the Cell instance in one of its methods.

Comment: @ScaryWombat The random values are only used to rotate the velocity vector in the update method. Each time the code loops, the random number is different, but it is the same for each instance of the Cell class. What I mean is that Cell A and Cell B get the a single result on frame 0, then another result in frame 1, but even if it changes from one frame to another, during that frame, all the random numbers generated are the same.

Comment: I suggest that you pare down this code to the simplest that still reproduces the problem, a decent [mre], and then post that code in your question. This will fully expose the problem for all to see, including yourself. Often you identify the issue yourself when attempting this most valuable exercise.

Comment: @ScaryWombat no, I mean the value that is passed to `vel.rotateDeg()`. I have edited the code in the question to make it clearer

Comment: `Vector.X` is static, so for every Cell, the `this.vel` will be pointing to the same static Object

Comment: Ah, I can't believe I didn't notice that, that was the problem. Thank you very much and sorry for the trouble!

Comment: That's OK, I hope that you can learn how to identify problems.